# PHP & MySQL check mysql left join with specified condition

Tags: php, mysql, sticky, xenforo

I'm using xenforo, that has tables:

- user: user_id, user_group_id
- thread: thread_id, user_id, sticky

I need a query to change user_group_id from 15 to 14 if they dont have any stick thread (sticky=0 in thread).

Is this possible with a left join, and if so how?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean an update query to change the user table? or just a select query that dynamically changes one of the field values?

Comment: one field value, Marc B

Answer (score 0):

```
update user u
set u.user_group_id=14
where u.user_group_id=15 and
  (select sticky from thread where thread_id = u.user_id)=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
UPDATE user SET user_group_id=14 WHERE user_group_id=15 AND 
0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thread WHERE sticky=0 AND user_id=user.user_id)
```

this does not use LEFT JOIN. Is it a must to use LEFT JOIN ?

Comment: Mysql return error: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: oops. I got a typo. change `=` to `IN`

Comment: I don't understand. I assume the two tables of `user_id` are PK and FK.

Comment: Mysqli prepare error: Unknown column 'thread.user_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: The problem is user has many threads, and if one of them are sticky and the another is non-sticky, and that user_id still listed in the SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
update user set user_group_id = 14 
where user_group_id = 15 
and user_id in (select user_id from threads where sticky=0)
```

**EDIT:**

In that case, instead of using a subquery, you can join both the tables while updating like below

```
update user u
inner join thread t on
    u.user_id = t.user_id and t.sticky = 0
set u.user_group_id = 14
where u.user_group_id = 15
```

See a demo sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b121/1.

Comment: I have 403,014 rows match the condition (select user_id from threads where sticky=0). Please help me for the most optimize for mysql?